# Migrate ParentReference from Google Drive Apis v2 to v3 in C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-drive-api

After reading the migration infos from Google on the Gdrive.v3 SDK here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration, I#m still not really sure how I can set the ParentReference (to the root folder) for a file correctly. Currently in v2 this is done via:

```
private string UploadToGDrive( Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService service, string uploadFile, string parent)
{
    var body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File
    {
        Name = Path.GetFileName(uploadFile),
        Description = uploadFile,
        MimeType = GetMimeType(uploadFile),
        Parents = new List<ParentReference> {new ParentReference {Id = parent}}
    };
}

private string GetMimeType(string fileName)
{
    var mimeType = "application/unknown";
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    if (extension == null) return mimeType;
    var ext = extension.ToLower();
    var regKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(ext);
    if (regKey?.GetValue("Content Type") != null) return mimeType;
    if (regKey != null) mimeType = regKey.GetValue("Content Type").ToString();
    return mimeType;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the document - [Inserting a file in a folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder#inserting_a_file_in_a_folder):

> To insert a file in a particular folder, specify the correct ID in the `parents` property of the file, as shown:

```
var folderId = "0BwwA4oUTeiV1TGRPeTVjaWRDY1E";
var fileMetadata = new File()
{
    Name = "photo.jpg",
    Parents = new List<string>
    {
        folderId
    }
};
FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream("files/photo.jpg",
    System.IO.FileMode.Open))
{
    request = driveService.Files.Create(
        fileMetadata, stream, "image/jpeg");
    request.Fields = "id";
    request.Upload();
}
var file = request.ResponseBody;
Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + file.Id);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I must have overseen this... It simply means in my case to replace

```
var body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File
{
    Name = Path.GetFileName(uploadFile),
    Description = uploadFile,
    MimeType = GetMimeType(uploadFile),
    Parents = new List<ParentReference> {new ParentReference {Id = parent}}
};
```

with

```
var body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File
{
    Name = Path.GetFileName(uploadFile),
    Description = uploadFile,
    MimeType = GetMimeType(uploadFile),
    Parents = new List<string> {parent}
};
```

(I've added this as an answer as it is to long for a comment).